# Using iCheck - Mobile has a tiny click area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, icheck

So, I'm using iCheck to create *beautiful* radiobuttons, but the problem is that they work fine on desktop, but when ran on mobile the radiobuttons have a clickbox of like 1px,1px meaning that I have to click in the very upper left corner for them to register the click.

This is my original html:

```
<input class="doneckr" type="radio" name="donep2" value="didn">
```

This is how the input renders to after the iCheck processing:

```
<div class="iradio_square-red" style="position: relative;">
    <input class="doneckr" type="radio" name="donep2" value="didn" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 44px; height: 44px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm using to initialize the iCheck processor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.doneck').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
    })

    $('.doneckr').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-red'
    })

    $('.donecke').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-orange',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-orange'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The 44x44px is small for fingers. Take a look [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/finger-friendly-design-ideal-mobile-touchscreen-target-sizes/) for a larger context. You should make it bigger. It's inline CSS and I'm assuming it comes directly from your plugin, meaning you will have to find the code (maybe it's a variable somewhere).

Also, make sure you include

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your header ([example here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)) in order to correctly display on high resolution (retina) devices. They have a lot 
of pixels, so be ware.